# if a cell in 1 column is equal to any cell in a 2nd column make new cell equal to a cell in a 3rd column in same row as cell in 2nd column

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns of different lengths. Columns 2 and 3 are equal, column 1 will always be smaller. I need to check using a 4th column if a cell in column 1 is equal to any cell in column 2, there will be no duplicates in column 2. If it is, make the cell in column 4 equal to the cell in column 3 that is in the same row as column 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Vlookup

```
=Vlookup($A1,$B:$C,2,FALSE)
```

Where A is column 1, b & c are column 2 & 3